# Spring Batch MultiResourceItemReader configuration issue with Custom ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

My current implementation below is working fine as long as in my publicFigureItemReader() I just set the Resource to the file I am trying to read. However, now that I got to this point I am trying to implement a MultiResourceItemReader which it will pass to the publicFigureItemReader() a bunch of files. As I have about 100 files in a single folder.

I have created the MultiResourceItemReader and now if I would use just a classic ItemReader I should just register this into my step **.reader(multiResourceItemReader())** but by doing so is not working because I am using a custom ItemReader so I am not sure how to register my MultiResourceItemReader.  Any pointers ?

If I try to register like so, the customItemWriter will stop working, I get a null pointer exception.

```
  @Bean
    Step associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep")
                .<Associate, Associate>chunk(1000)
                .reader(customItemReader())
                .writer(associateItemWriter(super.dataSource,super.namedParameterJdbcTemplate))
                .stream(multiResourceItemReader())
                //.stream((ItemStream) publicFigureItemReader())
                .build();
    }
```

If I try without registering the multiResourceItemReader() the exception is obvious *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Resource must not be null.*

```
      @Bean
Step associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep")
            .<Associate, Associate>chunk(1000)
            .reader(customItemReader())
            .writer(associateItemWriter(super.dataSource,super.namedParameterJdbcTemplate))
            //.stream(multiResourceItemReader())
            .stream((ItemStream) publicFigureItemReader())
            .build();
}
```

Here is a copy paste of my current Job Configuration Class.

```
@Value("classpath*:/data/mydata*.xml")
    private Resource[] inputFiles;


    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<PublicFigure> multiResourceItemReader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<PublicFigure> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        reader.setDelegate((ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<? extends PublicFigure>) publicFigureItemReader());
        reader.setResources(inputFiles);
        return reader;
    }


        @Bean
        ItemReader<PublicFigure> publicFigureItemReader() {
            StaxEventItemReader<PublicFigure> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
            //xmlFileReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\da\\myfile1.xml"));
            xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("PublicFigure");
            Jaxb2Marshaller publicFigMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
            publicFigMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Associate.class, PublicFigure.class);
            publicFigMarshaller.setUnmarshallerListener(new PublicFigureAssociateListener());
            xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(publicFigMarshaller);
            return xmlFileReader;
        }

        @Bean
        ItemReader<Associate> customItemReader() {
            return new AssociateItemReader(publicFigureItemReader());
        }



        @Bean
        ItemWriter<Associate> associateItemWriter(DataSource dataSource, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<Associate> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
            databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
            databaseItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

            databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT);

            ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Associate> associateItemPreparedStatementSetter = new AssociatePreparedStatementSetter();
            databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(associateItemPreparedStatementSetter);

            return databaseItemWriter;
        }


        @Bean
        Step associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep")
                    .<Associate, Associate>chunk(1000)
                    .reader(customItemReader())
                    .writer(associateItemWriter(super.dataSource,super.namedParameterJdbcTemplate))
                    //.stream(multiResourceItemReader())
                    .stream((ItemStream) publicFigureItemReader())
                    .build();
        }
```

The above configuration will throw an exception, even after changing the customItemReader to return the multiREsourceItemReader, see below:

```
 @Bean
    ItemReader<Associate> customItemReader() {
        //return new AssociateItemReader(publicFigureItemReader());
        return new AssociateItemReader(multiResourceItemReader());
    }
```

This is the stacktrace as a result

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Resource must not be null.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doOpen(StaxEventItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

The below stacktrace will come up when I register the multiReader and comment the publicFigureItemReader()), like so:

```
.stream(multiResourceItemReader())
 //.stream((ItemStream) publicFigureItemReader())
```

-This is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.springframework.core.io.Resource is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.core.io.Resource
        at private org.springframework.core.io.Resource io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.PublicFigure.resource
        at io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.PublicFigure
        at io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.PublicFigure io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.Associate.publicFigure
        at io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.Associate

    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:915) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:483) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createUnmarshaller(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:858) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:761) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:753) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:240) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readFromDelegate(MultiResourceItemReader.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readNextItem(MultiResourceItemReader.java:119) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:108) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.AssociateItemReader.read(AssociateItemReader.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.AssociateItemReader.read(AssociateItemReader.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromClasses(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:523) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:476) ~[spring-oxm-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `return new AssociateItemReader(publicFigureItemReader());` must be `return new AssociateItemReader(multiResourceItemReader());`

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci   I've tried that and I get an exception _org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader_. In a normal scenario with a simple ItemReader and ItemWriter you would register the MultiResourceReader in your step and it just works out of the box. In my case, in my step associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep() I am not sure how register the MultiResourceReader and that's because of the CustomItemReader implementation.

Comment: I've also tried to register the .stream(multiResourceItemReader()) and commented out the .stream((ItemStream) publicFigureItemReader()) here the MultiResource is getting called but I get the following exception _UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of 
org.springframework.core.io.Resource is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.this problem is related to the following location:
at org.springframework.core.io.Resource io.spring.batch.configuration.jobs.djsplit.djpersonsentities.PublicFigure.resource_

Comment: Edit question and add full stacktrace

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci, I've added both stacktraces

Comment: Annotate Associate#publicFigure wihth @XmlTransient